# Active Record fixture format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written some test for my controller but anytime I run the command rails test I get the error message active record format error. Any help  or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[image]

```
#this is what I have on my fixture.yml
one:
  contract_name: MyString
  contract_status: MyString
  services_rendered: MyString
  contract_value: MyString
  award_year: 1
  location: one


two:
  contract_name: MyString
  contract_status: MyString
  services_rendered: MyString
  contract_value: MyString
  award_year: 1
  location: two
```

Comment: Try to parse your yaml file into a hash by doing `YAML.load_file('path/to/your/file.yml')` and you will know if the error comes from your yaml file or elsewher

Comment: I guess you may have some illegal characters in the fixture file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving Active record fixture format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588340/resolving-active-record-fixture-format-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active record fixture format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580331/active-record-fixture-format-error)